# How do I choose parent node attribute and its child values using XML and Xquery?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, xquery

I have this:

```
<pss>
<ps n="А parent node" m="654564654" t="435,8551" a="2857,2716">
      <sc s="a1" a="25,4220"/>
      <sc s="a2" a="0"/>
      <sc s="a3" a="2395,9945"/>
</ps>
...
</pss>
```

I need to select "А parent node m attribute and a1-a2 a values in one query.
i tried this but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT ps.value('@m', 'nvarchar(50)') "parent node",
--       sc.value('@a1', 'nvarchar(50)') "название услуги",
--       sc.value('@a2', 'nvarchar(50)') "стоимость услуги",
       ps.value('@a3, 'nvarchar(50)') "b","
FROM   mts.dbo.bill 
OUTER APPLY xCol.nodes('//Report/rp/pss/ps') AS A(ps)
OUTER APPLY xCol.nodes('//Report/rp/pss/ps/sc/.') AS B(sc)
```

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `a1`, `a2` or `a3` attributes in the provided XML document!

**Use**:

```
  /pss/ps/@*[name(.)='n' or name(.)='m']
|
  /pss/ps/sc/@a
```

This is the XPath expression that selects the wanted nodes from the provided XML document. I am not sure how it should be combined into an SQL command.

Comment: thanx, but ERROR: XQuery [mts.dbo.bill.xCol.nodes()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:name()'.

Comment: "There are no a1, a2 or a3 attributes in the provided XML document!" - this is attribute "s" of <sc> node, sorry

Comment: @Kai: My answer is in pure XPath 1.0 -- you didn't specify XQuery as a tag!. Now I updated the answer and it will run both in XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 (XQuery is a superset of XPath 2.0).

Comment: Dimitre. I am quite new to all thу X... stuff. Will you please give me a solution to thу xml at the very top: <pss> is the root node and it has several <ps> nodes. <ps> nodes have <sc> nodes. What I need is: Get an attribute of <pss> node and all atributes of its <sc> nodes (repeats for each <ps> node).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @document xml
set @document = N'
<pss>
    <ps n="А parent node" m="654564654" t="435,8551" a="2857,2716">
          <sc s="a1" a="25,4220"/>
          <sc s="a2" a="0"/>
          <sc s="a3" a="2395,9945"/>
    </ps>
</pss>'


select
    pses.ps.value(N'@m', N'NVARCHAR(10)')
    , scs.sc.value(N'@s', N'NVARCHAR(2)')
from
    @document.nodes(N'//ps') pses(ps)
cross apply
    pses.ps.nodes(N'//sc') scs(sc)
```

Comment: And what's that supposed to do?